# Laravel 5 replicate() handle columns that have unique attribute

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, unique

I am using laravel's `replicate()` method of a Model to generate a copy of exiting instance. It works fine if there are no columns that are to be `unique`

In my case there are some columns that are to be unique so I use this

```
    $pr = Products::find(\Input::get('id'))->replicate();
    $pr['product_code'] = $pr->product_code . '_'.$pr['id'];
    $pr['name'] = $pr->name . '_'.$pr['id'];
    $pr->save();
```

This will make sure that if a product is replicated once it will handle the unique column problem. But if the product is replicated again it will cause the problem again.

How I can I solve this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would set in database `product_code` and `name` as nullables and then do something like this:

```
$product = Products::find(\Input::get('id'));
$newProduct = $product->replicate(['product_code', 'name']);
$newProduct->save();
$newProduct->product_code = $product->product_code.'_'.$newProduct->id;
$newProduct->name = $product->name.'_'.$newProduct->id;
$newProduct->save();
```

Of course you could wrap this into a function in case you do it in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

Recently ran into this issue, most efficient and effective was just to use unix time stamp. Here is another example to give you a better idea of what is going on without having to null fields and such.

```
    $page = Page::find($id);
    $duplicatePage = $page->replicate();
    $duplicatePage->name = 'Copy of ' . $page->name;
    $duplicatePage->slug = $page->slug . '-' . time();
    $duplicatePage->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

following [@Marcin Nabiałek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3593996/marcin-nabia%C5%82ek) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365820/1155507) I solved the issue with small enhancements

```
$product = Products::find(\Input::get('id'));
$newProduct = $product->replicate();
$newProduct->save();
$newProduct->product_code = str_replace("_".$product->id,"",$product->product_code).'_'.$newProduct->id;
$newProduct->name = str_replace("_".$product->id,"",$product->name).'_'.$newProduct->id;
$newProduct->save();
```

This will remove the `old _id` from the name and product code for an entry which already has `_id` at the end and then add the `new _id`.